# getting value from input and displaying in a div

Tags: javascript, html, input, vanilla-forums

I am trying to get the value of an input and display it in a div under it, while the user is typing. and i want to do it with vanilla js. no j query.

MY HTML:

```
<div id="userInputBox">
<input id="inputText" type="text"      
placeholder="Enter your question" size = "50" onkeyup="myDisplay()"/>
</div>
<div class="displayQuestion"></div>
```

MY JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
var showQuestion = document.getElementsByClassName('displayQuestion');
function myDisplay(e){
showQuestion.innerHTML = input;
}
```

Comment: Please have a look below

Comment: I answered your question with `className` but you have accepted the `id` solution. May I know the reason please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function myDisplay(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  var showQuestion = document.getElementById('displayQuestion');
  showQuestion.innerHTML = input;
}
```

```html
<div id="userInputBox">
  <input id="inputText" type="text"
placeholder="Enter your question" size = "50" onkeyup="myDisplay(this.value)"/>
</div>
<div id="displayQuestion"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with `VannilaJS` way,

**Recommendation**: Change the name of the function `myDisplay()` to something meaningful like `displayQuestion()`

```js
var targetElm = document.getElementsByClassName('displayQuestion');
var inputElm = document.getElementById('inputText');

function myDisplay() {
  if(targetElm && targetElm.length > 0){
    targetElm[0].innerHTML = inputElm.value;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div id="userInputBox">
      <input id="inputText" type="text"      
      placeholder="Enter your question" size ="50" onkeyup="myDisplay()"/>
      </div>
    <div class="displayQuestion"></div>
```

Comment: @KashaCathy I answered your question with `className` but you have accepted the `id` solution. May I know the reason please?